# how to get stored procedure's batches query in different dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fetch all the data from one stored procedure for different different Dataset in a single page.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Details](@status  int, @Id int)
AS
begin

Select u.Id,u.FName,u.ImageName,u.ImagePath,u.Sex FROM [User] as u
 where u.Id IN (SELECT MyId as Id FROM Friends WHERE FriendId=@Id AND FriendStatus=0)

Select Points,FName from [User] where Id=@Id

SELECT ImagePath from [User] where Id=@Id
end
GO
```

Now, how I can bind datatable/dataset for individual query.
Example: query1 for dataset1, query2 for dataset2, query3 for dataset3

If this is not possible then which is the best way to avoid connecting database each time for fetching different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer but still need a suggestion whether this worth using.

```
private void GetMultiSelect()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect1"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_AllDetail";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            sqlParam.Value = 1;
            //dataset object to get all select statement results
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //sql dataadoptor to fill dataset
            using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                //here all select statements are fill in dataset object
                adp.Fill(ds);

                //now u can fetch each and every select statement by providing table index in dataset

                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    //select statement result in dt..
                }

                //or instead of loop u can specify the index
               GridView1.DataSource= ds.Tables[1]; // first select statement result
               GridView1.DataBind();
               GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // second select statement result
               GridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that with datasets, but you can always fall back to lower lever ADO.NET API. SqlReader supports multiple result sets via NextResult method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

You could just as easily hand back an array of DataTables without wrapping them in a DataSet. Better from a resource perspective, since DataSet is a pretty heavyweight class. DataSet is pretty much an in-memory relational database that provides all sorts of support for building in relationships between DataTables and enforcement of constraints.

There's no requirement that a DataTable be part of a DataSet at all. It's fundamentally just a container.

Here's the code:

```
static DataSet[] ExecStoredProcedure()
{
  DataSet[] instance = null ;
  const string credentials = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sandbox;Integrated Security=SSPI;" ;

  using ( SqlConnection  connection = new SqlConnection( credentials ) )
  using ( SqlCommand     command    = connection.CreateCommand() )
  using ( SqlDataAdapter adapter    = new SqlDataAdapter( command ) )
  using ( DataSet        results    = new DataSet() )
  {

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
    command.CommandText = @"someStoredProcedure" ;

    connection.Open() ;
    adapter.Fill( results ) ;
    connection.Close() ;

    List<DataSet> list = new List<DataSet>( results.Tables.Count ) ;
    while ( results.Tables.Count > 0 )
    {
      DataTable dt = results.Tables[0] ;

      results.Tables.RemoveAt(0) ;

      DataSet ds = new DataSet() ;
      ds.Tables.Add( dt ) ;
      list.Add(ds) ;

    }

    instance = list.ToArray() ;

  }

  return instance ;
}
```

Another options to execute a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets, return the specified result set as a DataTable. Execution of the stored procedure is short-circuited when the desired result set is reached:

```
static DataTable ExecStoredProcedure( string someStoredProcedure , int desiredTableNumber )
{
  DataTable instance = null ;
  const string credentials = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sandbox;Integrated Security=SSPI;" ;

  using ( SqlConnection  connection = new SqlConnection( credentials ) )
  using ( SqlCommand     command    = connection.CreateCommand() )
  {

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
    command.CommandText = someStoredProcedure ;

    connection.Open() ;

    using ( SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
    {
      int i = 0 ;
      while ( reader.HasRows )
      {

        // toss any unwanted results ;
        if ( instance != null ) instance.Dispose() ; // toss unwanted results

        instance = new DataTable() ;
        instance.Load( reader ) ;

        if ( i == desiredTableNumber || reader.IsClosed ) break ;

        ++i ;

      }

      if ( i != desiredTableNumber )
      {
        if ( instance != null ) instance.Dispose() ;
        instance = null ;
      }

      // try to tidy up so the connection isn't hose, if we short-circuited execution
      command.Cancel() ;
      reader.Close() ;

    }

    command.Cancel() ;
    connection.Close() ;

  }

  return instance ;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks. But in your example above it doesn't seem you are filling dataset for specific query. You can see in a stored procedure  there are three "select" statement so for each one I want to fill in different dataset or datatable.

Comment: See my amended answer. For what it's worth, what are you trying to accomplish by this? Database connections, by default, are cached. Once you've made the connection, subsequent "opens" are cheap as they just retrieve the already-open connection from cache. Further, if you're only interested in result set 3 of 5, you're doing a lot of extra work in the database that gets thrown away.